# Could not resolve project :RNAdMob

Tags: android, react-native, admob

How to fix this error. I already made a match between my compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion with 23 and 23.0.3 but I couldn't build.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    }
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+'
compile project(':RNAdMob')
}
```

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.

  > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
  >   Could not resolve project :RNAdMob.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :app > project :react-native-admob
  >   Unable to find a matching configuration of project :RNAdMob:
  >         - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

Comment: You do not have the Project included. You have to add the module.

Comment: Add this module project :RNAdMob its giving error

Comment: Have you tried : `Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle files`

Comment: Inside of android/build.gradle: do you have the maven thing? `maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" 
        }`

Comment: You can exclude gms if you want `compile (project(':RNAdMob')){
            exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
        }`